# Detecting which 'using' statements are required

Tags: c#, .net

Let's assume that I have the following code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace myNamespace {
    static class myClass {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // Code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Let's also assume that the comment right above is replaced with some code in C# which can may or may not require any of the namespaces that are included in the [.NET Framework Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt472912(v=vs.110).aspx).

Moreover, to make things simple, let's assume that the code does not include any comments.

I'm using a StringBuilder to store and modify this code and what I want to do is to add all necessary 'using' statements.

For example, if the code uses a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), then I should add the '[using System.Collections.Generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic(v=vs.110).aspx);' statement. This should work for all possible 'using' statements.

I thought of using regular expressions. For example, I could use a Regex which tries to find all at least one of classes which are defined in the System.Collections.Generic namespace and if it successfully finds one, then it should stop searching and add the 'using System.Collections.Generic;' statement.

However, considering how many namepaces there are in the .NET Class Library and how many classes and interfaces are defined in each of these, made me think that this approach would result in a large and slow code.

Is there a better, faster, smarter approach to this?

Comment: Just go buy ReSharper. https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: Are you generating this code at runtime or something? Because the IDE will do this for you, and certainly add-ins like ReSharper will, too. Also, it is worth noting that adding using statements will *not* "result in a large and slow code". The compiler will just ignore the ones that it doesn't need. It might take a *slight* bit longer to process a file with a bunch of using statements, but it will not be relevant considering the overall cost of compilation.

Comment: If visual studio is your IDE, it offers to add `using` statements as you go, via IntelliSense smart tagging. There even is a "remove unused usings" editor command, for cleanup.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes I'm actually generating code at runtime. When I said that the code will be slow, I was actually talking about the process of adding all the necessary references (since there is a lot of searching involved) and not about the performance of the code that will later be generated.

Comment: Well, in generated code, `using` statements don't make a lot of sense. Just fully qualify each reference. You know the full name of the class at the time you write the code-gen, so don't lose that information. For example, if you want to generate code that uses `List`, you know that `List` is actually `System.Collections.Generic.List`, so that's what your code-gen should call it. No need for a `using` reference now, and absolutely no speed loss. The only advantage of `using` statements is code readability, and no one reads auto-generated code.

Comment: The Omnisharp server can detect unsed and missign using statements.

Comment: You'll get the hang of this pretty quickly.  There's certainly help available to get up to speed, in VS2015 you can click the light-bulb and it automatically adds the using directive.